# write/writeLines to multiple connections (e.g console output and log file)

Tags: r, logfile

I'm using `writeLines()` to create a log file, but I'd like to see the text written to the log file also in the console. Is there a way to define a connection that writes text into a file and simultaneously prints the text in the console?

Something like:

```
con1 <- file("log.txt", "w")
con2 <- console()

writeLines("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", con=c(con1, con2))

close(con1)
```

My solution so far needs some extra lines to do that.

```
con1 <- file("log.txt", "w")

log.txt <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

writeLines(log.txt)
writeLines(log.txt, con=con1)

close(con1)
```

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `split` argument to `sink()`.  For example,

```
con1 <- file("log.txt", "w")
sink(con1, split = TRUE)
log.txt <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
writeLines(log.txt)
sink()  # back to normal
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. What if I don't want to have every writeLines() in the log file, but in the console?

`con1 <- file("log.txt", "w")`
`sink(con1, split = TRUE)`
log.txt <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
writeLines(log.txt)
txt.console <- "text console"
writeLines(txt.console) # this text should only appear in the console but not in the log file`

Comment: See the last line of code.  You can call `sink(con1, split=TRUE)` and `sink()` multiple times.